# Is there a shortcut to convert plain text list into a python list? ( strings with comma)

Tags: python, string, list

I'm copying and pasting this list of hex codes, and I want to format it into a python list more easily than going through and typing `' ',` around each one. Are there any shortcuts for this? It's fine for a short list, but for a longer list, this would be tedious

input:

```
#ffa600
#ff8538
#ff6959
#f05675
#d0508a
#a85196
#7a5296
#4d508b
#244a76
#01405d
```

desired output:

`list = ['#ffa600', '#ff8538', etc]`

Comment: That will depend entirely on your editor/IDE.

Comment: If you have those data as a string then a default split() on the string will give you a list in the format you need

Comment: How are you loading your text file?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use python interepreter for this kind of job. Using triples quotes makes it easier.

```
input = """#ffa600
#ff8538
#ff6959
#f05675
#d0508a
#a85196
#7a5296
#4d508b
#244a76
#01405d
"""
output = input.split("\n")
```

Leads to this list that you can copy paste

```
output = ['#ffa600', '#ff8538', '#ff6959', '#f05675', '#d0508a', '#a85196', '#7a5296', '#4d508b', '#244a76', '#01405d']
```

Comment: Using the name of a Python built-in function as a variable name is rarely a good idea. Also, in this case, there is no need to pass any parameter(s) to split()

Answer (score 0):

Use [str.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)

```
>>> d = """\
... abc
... def
... ghi
... """
>>> d.splitlines()
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Answer (score 0):

First copy all of your hex values to a text file as test.txt

test.txt:

```
#ffa600
#ff8538
#ff6959
#f05675
```

Now read each line in text file with a for loop

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
my_list = []
X=0

for i in f.readlines(): 
    my_list.insert(x, i.rstrip("\n")) 
    x=x+1
f.close()

print("list =", my_list)
```

Output:

```
list = ['#ffa600','#ff8538','#ff6959','#f05675']
```